# send data to the div tag only if the data is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax code where it gets the time in seconds and pass it to the div tag to be shown. The thing is, I only want it to pass the data to the div tag if it pass the if statement's test to save space. For example, I only want it to pass the data to the div tag if seconds in less than 30, but if it doesn't pass anything to the div tag, the div tag shows up as null. Instead of it showing up as null, I want it to stay at the 30 second mark without the ajax function having to pass the data to the div tag. I don't know if what I'm saying makes any sense to you, but if it does, is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

#### testing1.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function timeoutAjax(url,id,timeout) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
             setTimeout(function() { timeoutAjax(url,id,timeout); }, timeout);
           }

      });

}

timeoutAjax("testing2.php","seconds",1000);

</script>

<div id = "seconds"></div>
```

#### testing2.php

```
<?php

$date = date("s");

if ($date < 30){
echo $date;
}

?>
```

I also don't want anything like the below, because the whole point of this, is to save space, and if I echo it anyway, it passes the data to the div tag. I don't want to pass the data to the div tag if it doesn't pass the if statement, but I also don't want the input to be null, since that happens if nothing is passed to the div tag. Is there a way to just keep the div tag as it were before?

#### testing2.php

```
<?php

$date = date("s");

if ($date < 30){
echo $date;
}
else {
echo 30;}

?>
```

Comment: if (data && data <= 30) document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;

Comment: jQuery will evaluate the text returned by `testing2.php` as `null` or whatever content it has. Add an `if` statement in your Ajax to solve it. Like Roberto said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `else` statement afterwards, which does `echo 30`.
Instead of setting it to nothing, `null`, you can set it to 30.

```
if($date < 30){
  echo $date;
}else{
  echo 30;
}
```

Comment: No. It does the same thing as the above. I'm trying to get it to stay at 30 seconds if it goes over 30 seconds, without it having to pass the data to the div tag.

Comment: I also don't want anything like echo "30"; because that still passes the data to the div tag, and thus wastes unnecessary space.

Comment: My apologies. I misread your question. It is now rectified. What do you mean by "save space" and "waste space"?

Comment: It's something like this. I go check something in the database. If it returns as true, I want it to pass the information to the div tag, but if it returns as false, I don't want anything to be passed to the div tag. Because if nothing is passed to the div tag it'll save bandwidth space, wouldn't it? Or even loading time.

Comment: @frosty - No, you've used the same bandwidth ... perhaps even more since the request waits and timeout.

Comment: @Roberto Please explain.

Comment: The broadband is used to pass stuff to `testing2.php`. Therefore, there is no space issue there.

Comment: Yeah, but then the stuff from testing2.php is return to testing1.php. Doesn't that take space?

Comment: Check Roberto's comment in your question. He has it.

Comment: @bcdan But you're both saying that it's using the same bandwidth. It doesn't matter if it uses the same bandwidth, then, does it? Because the whole point of this was me trying to save bandwidth space.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to say for sure. But the bandwidth is negligible. Just choose something and do it.